# What is the kind of filter does keras uses for conv2D in CNN?

Tags: python-3.x, frameworks, neural-network, deep-learning, keras

I just didn't understand what kind of filter does keras framework for convolution neural network uses in the following line of code, is it for horizontal edge detection or verticals or any edge or any other feature??
Here it's a 7*7  32 filters with stride of 1 which we convolve with X

```
x= Conv2D(32, (7, 7), strides = (1, 1), name = 'conv0')(X)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convolutional filters are not pre-disposed to any particular feature.  Rather, they "learn" their duties through training.  These features evolve organically through training, depending on what enhances the prediction accuracy on the far end of the model.  The model will gradually learn which features work well for the given inputs, depending on the ground truth and back propagation.

The critical trick in this is a combination of back prop and initialization.  When we randomly initialize the filters, the important part isn't so much what distribution we choose; rather, it's that there are *some* differences, so that the filters will differentiate well.

For instance, in typical visual processing applications, the model's first layer (taking the `conv0` label as a hint) will learn simple features: lines, curves, colour blobs, etc.  Whatever filter *happens* to be initialized most closely to a vertical line detector, will eventually evolve into that filter.  In the early training, it will receive the highest reinforcement from back propagation's "need" for vertical lines.  Those filters that are weaker at verticals will get less reinforcement, then see their weights reduced (since our "star pupil" will be sufficient to drive the vertical-line needs), and will eventually evolve to recognize some other feature.

Overall, the filters will evolve into a set of distinct features, as needed by the eventual output.  One brute-force method of finding the correct quantity of features is to put in too many -- see how many of them learn something useful, then reduce the quantity until you have clean differentiation on a minimal set of filters.  In the line of code you present, someone has already done this, and found that CONV0 needs about 32 filters for this topology and application.

Does that clear up the meaning?

Comment: Hi @Prune, this answer is very useful, thanks. A further question, how can I know that the learned features are useful?? (I know this question is probably out of the initial question in this post, but if you have any bibliography where I can read about I'll appreciate it)

Comment: To see what is useful, look at the contribution each filter makes to the next layer in the fully-trained model.  If the filter's coefficients are near zero, then it contributes little, and can likely be deleted (i.e. reconfigure your model topology to have one fewer kernel in that layer, and retrain).  Creating a new model topology requires a lot of experimentation of this sort.